# Finding partial match in array

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab any data that has a key of "release_"... I think I'm supposed to use array_filter, but I'm having difficulty writing the proper function for param 2.

Here is my array:

```
Array
    (
    [release_date] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-03-31
        )

    [duration] => Array
        (
            [type] => time
            [value] => 136
        )
    [directors] => Array
        (
            [type] => page
            [value] => 13,14
        )
    [writers] => Array
        (
            [type] => page
            [value] => 13,14
        )
    [release_us] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-03-30
        )
    [release_ge] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-06-16
        )
    )
```

I'd like my return array to have only the arrays where release_ is present.. so it would look like:

```
Array
    (
    [release_date] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-03-31
        )

    [release_us] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-03-30
        )
    [release_ge] => Array
        (
            [type] => date
            [value] => 1999-06-16
        )
    )
```

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1596343/2112743

Comment: Are you looking for a PHP built-in function? Because a `foreach` loop would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function preg_grep_keys( $pattern, $input, $flags = 0 )
{
    $keys = preg_grep( $pattern, array_keys( $input ), $flags );
    $vals = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
    {
        $vals[$key] = $input[$key];
    }
    return $vals;
}
```

The usage:

`preg_grep_keys("/release_/", $yourArray);`

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `foreach` to loop through your original array:

```
$nArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'release_') !== false) {
        $nArr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Or in functional form:

```
function checkKeys($arr, $keyCheck) {
    $nArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($key, $keyCheck) !== false) {
            $nArr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $nArr;
}
```

And then to use `$release = checkKeys($myArray, 'release_');`